# Pipe error in [Echo !file!|findstr]

Tags: batch, pipe, findstr

with this script I read a Log file with filenames and search a string (with wildcards) in these list but the pipe for the findstr function doesn't work.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f  %%A in (./Log.txt) do (
    set "file=%%A"
    echo !file!
    echo !file!|findstr ".*_DE.pdf"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 echo "gefunden"!file!
)
```

I get the error:
*Ein Prozess hat versucht, zu einer nicht bestehenden Pipe zu schreiben.*

translated: *A process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe*

The test in the command line is okay

I hope there is a syntax failure ore a missing option?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the error with your script and a short `Log.txt` file, but I was able to reproduce it with the following one-liner: `for /l %i in () do @echo test | findstr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to get that message is if the right side of your pipe (`findstr`) closes before the left side (`echo`) is finished writing to stdout.

I don't see how that is possible unless `findstr` is not executing the correct command. Make sure you do not have any `findstr.bat` or the like in your current folder, or in your PATH.

One way to avoid such problems, (or confirm this is the problem), is to provide the full path to FINDSTR.

```
echo !file!|"%windir%\system32\findstr.exe" ".*_DE.pdf"
```

If the change above fixes the problem, then you must have a rogue FINDSTR executable somewhere.

Comment: thanks a lot! I had a finstr.bat in the same directory